# Wiring help needed with 2 separate lights and switches

Tags: electrical, switch, light

I have a single switch in my garage for the light outside my garage. I have a single switch at my front door for my porch. I want to have it so either switch will turn on both the garage, and porch light.

I ran 14/3 wire from 1 switch to the other. I have two 3-way switches. I thought that's what I needed, but I'm not sure if it's a 4-way.

#### Front door switch

[image]

#### Garage switch

[image]

Comment: Can you also run a 14/2 cable?

Comment: I could, but don't have one. Was hoping I could use everything I already have

Comment: I do have extra 14/3 I could run, and take the red out to make it 14/2

Comment: Smart boy Doug.  You took pictures before taking everything apart.

Comment: Which switch box is that a photo of the inside of, and can you post a photo of the inside of the other switch box as well please?

Comment: That pic is by my front door. The image in the link above is the box in the garage. The box in the garage has the 14/3 wire it's just not shown in that pic.

Comment: It looks like both boxes have two switches in them.  Which switch in each box (left or right) are you wanting to convert to three-way?

Comment: Yes they do. Front door (first photo) left switch, and the other photo it's the right switch.

Comment: If it's easier I could just add another switch at my front door making it a 3 gang box. 1 switch for the garage light, porch light, and the other switch. Than the garage can remain the same. I can do that with the 14/3 I ran if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

This needs to be done in a 2-step process.

### Rewire it so one of the switches powers both lights.

For this, we need to run a /2 cable between the switches.  (or alternately, from the controlling switch direct to the light).   If you use /3 cable, leave the full length intact on the useless wire, but cap it off. Could come in handy later.

Inside the non-controlling (temporarily defunct) switch box, take the cable (hot and neutral) that goes to the light (i.e. the switched hot on the old switch) -- and mark its black wire *blue*, and its white wire *gray*. On the new /2 cable, also mark *both ends* that same way.   Note  that we are marking the white wire gray.

In the non-controlling box, connect these two gray wires to each other, and  these two blue wires to each other.  They will effectively "pass through" this box without connecting to any switches.  That will be permanently that way.

Back in the controlling box, you need to pigtail or *legally* double-tap the switch. Assuming there is one single bundle of white wires, the gray wire joins it.   The blue wire goes to the switched side of the switch.  (if it's on 24x7 you got the wrong side).

OK, so now you have both lights working from one of the switches.

### Upgrade this to a 3-way circuit

Now, lay a /3 cable between the two switch boxes.

Then follow my instructions on the other post! *Remember we will not touch the blue/gray splice in the far box*.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That seems like a lot of work. I just finished the project. I bought a 3 gang box for the front door, and used a 3 way in the garage, and 3 way at the front door. So I have 3 light switches at my front door. One for the porch light, one or inside the front door, and one for the garage light.  I do appreciate all the help, but It was a lot of work running the 14/3 wire let a lone adding another.

Comment: @Doug21 oh, that,s a much simpler solution.  I was under the impression that you needed to switch the porch light from the garage!  In the future I strongly recommend you figure out how the wiring needs to be done *before* installing cable (or in fact, wven buying it).